# SQL Server add frequency column to existing table

Tags: sql-server

If I have a table with a column that contains duplicate values. How do I add a column to that table that displays how many entries in the table contain that value.

I know that you can use:

```
    select id, COUNT(id) as freq
    from mytable
    group by id
    order by freq desc
```

to get the frequency, but how do I display this in a new column in the original table?

Comment: Would you please give us an example?

Comment: Why put that in a table? You need to update that every time the records change

Comment: I have building geometry data, and there are a ton of buildings that correspond to the same ID. I would like to merge them using the STUnion function.

Answer (score 2):

It'll depend on how often you insert/update/delete that table, vs. how often you need to select it.

I'd probably go with a view, as Joe C suggests.

However, if you don't insert/update/delete often, and you really really want it on the table, you can do a trigger on insert, update, and delete, so the information is calculated whenever it needs to. It'll be miserable insert, update, and delete performance, so keep that in mind:

```
create trigger dbo.MyTable_IUD
on dbo.MyTable
after insert, update, delete
as
begin
    update m
    set _freq = counts.freq
    from dbo.MyTable m
    join
    (
        select id, count(1) [freq]
        from dbo.MyTable
        where id in
        (
           select id from inserted 
           union select id from deleted
        )
        group by id
    ) counts on m.id = counts.id;
end;
go
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a view if you need to do this.

```
Create View vMyTable As
Select M.*, F.Freq 
   From MyTable M 
   Join (Select id, Count(id) Freq From MyTable Group By id) F On F.id = M.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

select id, freq
from mytable m
inner join (select id, COUNT(id) as freq
from mytable
group by id
order by freq desc) f
on f.id = m.id