# SQL- add frequency column to data

Tags: sql

I have a dataset which has categorical variables. I need to add a column to that dataset that will show the frequency for the corresponding level.

For example, assume you have a dataset that has a state column. This is the input dataset. In the output dataset, for every row now, there will also be a column that will tell me how the number of times that particular state occurred in the dataset.

#### Example

```
# Date_Built    Square_Footage  Num_Beds    Num_Baths   State   Price
# 01/01/1920    1700            3           2           NY      700,000   

# Date_Built    Square_Footage  Num_Beds    Num_Baths   State   Price     Freq_State
# 01/01/1920    1700            3           2           NY      700,000   4,500
```

In this example, a `Freq_State` is column has been added which captures the information that `NY` appears `4500` times in the `State` column

This is what I have so far, but it only gives me the frequency of the columns. I went through a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284864/sql-server-add-frequency-column-to-existing-table) but both the answers suggest creating a new view. Is there a way I can directly add this column without having to create a new table

```
select
  count(grp_column) as freq_encode,
  grp_column
from
  df_sql_tbl
group by
  grp_column
```

Comment: which datase system are you using?

Comment: @RadimBača I am doing this in pyspark actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       (SELECT count(*) cnt FROM df_sql_tbl WHERE state = t1.state)
FROM df_sql_tbl t1
```

Comment: what is `t1` here?

Comment: your main table, which in this case is df_sql_tbl

Answer (score 3):

Spark SQL should support the window functions, therefore, try to use them

```
select *,
       count(*) over (partition by state)
from your_table
```

Comment: accepting chris's answer as he answered first and also bc his approach has a runtime advantage to it as well. Nearly twice for a `10^6x3` dataset

Comment: @ClockSlave interesting. Cheers.